# --Is it possible to detect the ID of the element clicked with React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I want to use the same event handler for menu items when they are clicked.

In vanilla JavaScript the event handler 'this' value will point to the element and you can simply use `this.id`, how is this done in React.

clickHandler2 and clickHandler3 I want to make into one event handler.  The only thing different is the element clicked on.

The code is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

class MobileMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.clickHandler1 = this.clickHandler1.bind(this);
    this.clickHandler2 = this.clickHandler2.bind(this);
    this.clickHandler3 = this.clickHandler3.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      current_item: 'nav_fave'
      previous_item: null
    };
  }

  clickHandler1 () {
    this.toggleMenu();
  }

  clickHandler2 () {
    // MenuPage.flip('fave');
    this.toggleMenu();
    this.toggleMarker($A.el('#nav_fave'));
  }

  clickHandler3 () {
    // MenuPage.flip('splash');
    this.toggleMenu();
    this.toggleMarker($A.el('#nav_splash'));
  }

  toggleMarker (current_item) {

    this.setState({
      current_item: current_item
    });

    if ((this.previous_item !== undefined) && (this.previous_item !== current_item)) {
      this.previous_item.style.borderBottom = '';
    }
    if (this.previous_item !== current_item) {
      current_item.style.borderBottom = '3px solid #31baed';
    }
    this.previous_item = current_item;
  }

  toggleMenu () {
    if (window.getComputedStyle($A.el('#top_menu_list'), null).display === 'block') {
      $('#icon_bars').toggleClass('active');
      $('#top_menu').slideToggle();
    }
  }
  // ... snip 
}

export default MobileMenu
```

Comment: Since you're using a `jQuery` selector are you sure you just didn't forget the `#` in front of `this.id`? **Example:** `this.toggleMarker($A.el('#'this.id));` Also have you tried to see what `this.id` returns, maybe `console.log(this.id);` or `console.log(this);` to ensure it is targeting/returning what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the event parameter and use its `target` property:

```
clickHandler2 (e) {
    var id = e.target.id;
}
```

The `this` in your case is the `class` it self by the way.

Example:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}


handleChange(e){
  const {id, value} = e.target;
  console.log('id is - ' + id + ' and the value is: ' + value);
}

  render(){
    return(
    <div>
     <input id="input1" placeholder="type something" onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </div>
      
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```